# Autodetect Lead Type in HTML

Tags: html, salesforce, lead

Our team plans to send out emails to clients.
What type of code are we to insert in the HTML wherein it will detects what type of Salesforce lead type when they click the email link that is redirected to a landing page..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
    $xEmail = new EmailToReceiver;
    mysql_query("query");
    $xEmail->SendEmail(arguments);
    
   
 class EmailtoReceiver extends Mysql
    {
        public function SendEmail(arguments) // Get Parameter
        {
          $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
          $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-13249-1' . "\r\n";
          $headers .= "From: $From \r\n";
          
          $Subject="abc";
          $Msgx="1234";
          $Msgx.= "Hello World";
          
          $flag = mail($To,$Subject,$Msgx,$headers);   
        }
    }
?>
```

Hi! Hope you are well i think above code could help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).